# How to match resource with a specific rdfs:label

Tags: rdf, sparql

I wrote the following query to match resources with a specific label, but i get nothing

```
Select ?res 

Where {?res rdfs:label "London"^^xsd:string . }
```

I typed it in http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ which has the following prefix set

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
```

is there anything that i am missing ?

-M-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the language of the string.

Example for English (`@en`):

```
Select ?res 

Where {?res rdfs:label "London"@en . }
```

---

If you want to find all occurences of this string, no matter in which language, you could use a `FILTER` (but the query will be slow):

```
Select ?res Where {

?res rdfs:label ?label . 
FILTER (str(?label) = "London")
}
```